# read/write to array plist with Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, plist

Im trying to read a plist that contains an Array of Ints .
This is my first time using them  , and i can read them in fine , but the plist doesn't update when i write to it.

here's my code for the reading and writing..

```
class FavouritesManager {
    var myArray:NSMutableArray = [0]
    func loadDataPlist(){
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
        let documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0)as NSString
        let path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("FavouriteIndex.plist")
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager() 
        if(!fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path))
        {
            let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("FavouriteIndex", ofType: "plist")
            fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundle!, toPath: path, error:nil)
        }
        myArray = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path)!
        println(myArray)
    }
    func writeToPlist(indexValue:Int) {

        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("FavouriteIndex", ofType: "plist"){
            myArray.addObject(indexValue)
            myArray.addObject(indexValue+5)
            myArray.addObject(indexValue+10)
            myArray.addObject(indexValue+15)
            myArray.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
        }
    }
```

The purpose of this code is to store the index of the tableViewCell that has been favourited so that I can display that row in my favourite tableViewControllwe

BTW - my plist looks like this...
[image]
Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are loading the plist into your documents directory in `loadDataPlist()`, but you are still pulling the plist from it's original location in your `writeToPlist(indexValue:)` function. So you are trying to write to a plist at a readonly location. Change your write function to this:

```
func writeToPlist(indexValue:Int) {
    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    var path = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("MyPlist.plist")

    if var plistArray = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path) {
        plistArray.addObject(indexValue)
        plistArray.addObject(indexValue+5)
        plistArray.addObject(indexValue+10)
        plistArray.addObject(indexValue+15)
        plistArray.writeToFile(path, atomically: false)
    }
}
```

Note that instead of adding the values to `myArray` I'm only writing to the plist. You'll have to decide if you want to maintain the two arrays (the local variable `myArray` and the array in the plist) depending on what you're using this for. Either way, this should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks @timgcarlson for your answer , but 1 questions ,,
Whats the difference between loading for my bundle and loading from the documents documentary ?
would this be enough to load the file , 
            let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("FavouriteIndex", ofType: "plist")
?

Comment: The bundle is what you get from your installed app. This is a *read-only* directory, so you cannot modify any files stored in the bundle, nor can you add any files to the bundle. The documents directory is *read-write*, and is typically where you store user-data for basic apps. This is why in your `loadDataPlist()` function you are first checking if the plsit exists in the Documents directory, before copying it from the bundle to the Documents directory.

Comment: To specifically answer your question, it is not enough to just get the bundle if you are intending to write to that file (which you are doing). Here is the documentation on iOS File System Basics... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html